# hiding and/or denying access to files and folders in cyber duck via iam/s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, cyberduck

I'm using cyberduck on mac and I'm trying to prevent the user from accessing the certain directories via IAM policy for s3. I have it working to the point where it will block the user from accessing a folder namespace they are not supposed to, but one thing I noticed is that the user can still access files at the level above their designated folder (the folder the user is allowed to access is called images) from within cyberduck. example:

```
/images/

/afile1

/afile2

/afile3

/restrictedFolder1/
/restrictedFolder2/
```

so what I'm wondering is, if I can restrict access to the files outside of that user's folder or if i can't then can I hide those files (or just nor return them in the query) via IAM?

my policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListingOfBrandcentralPRDBucket",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",

        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "images/"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ListObjectsForTheImagesFolder",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "images/initial/",
                    "images/REJECTED/",
                    "assets/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "GrantPromissionsForTheImagesFolder",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/images/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: The example you gave does not match the IAM policy you posted (I do not see any user/home rules in your policy)

Does each user have his/her own bucket or are you looking to use a shared bucket?

Comment: so it's only one bucket, but it's not really about other users per say, more about the user this policy is attached to not being able to access certain things in that bucket. this policy is attached to the user directly in IAM. I'll adjust the example pathes